# RxJS Observable.if executes both statements

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

So I am relatively new to RxJs and Observable patterns in general and am currently struggling to understand some of the features provided and why they behave the way they do.

Here is a code snippet :

```
Observable.if( //can also be onErrorResumeNext
  () => true,
  Observable.fromPromise(
    fetch('/'+ locale + '_state.json', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.json();
    })
  ),
  Observable.fromPromise(
    fetch('/'+ defaultLocale + '_state.json', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.json();
    })
  )
)
```

Why do both of these statements gets executed? Am I doing something/approaching this in the wrong way or is this expected behaviour? Returning something more simple like in the example of [Observable.if](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/if.md) works fine, but as far as I understand RxJs is meant to be mainly for asynchronous data so should not the example above behave the same way?

I am aware I can rewrite the behaviours of Observable.if and Observable.onErrorResumeNext using Observable.mergeMap and thats what I ended up doing but it feels like I am missing something out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `promise` is not lazy and executes immediately. To easiest way to make a computation lazy is to use `.defer` like that:

```
Observable.if( //can also be onErrorResumeNext
  () => true,
  Observable.defer(() =>
    fetch('/'+ locale + '_state.json', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.json();
    })
  ),
  Observable.defer(() =>
    fetch('/'+ defaultLocale + '_state.json', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.json();
    })
  )
)
```

`.defer` will automatically upgrade a promise to an `observable`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `fetch()` twice and passing the result to `Observable.if()`. RxJs has no ability to control which one is called because you are *already calling both* before `Observable.if()` even runs.

The second and third parameters of your `Observable.if()` contain a lot of duplicate code. Why not rewrite this like so:

```
Observable.if(() => true, locale, defaultLocale)
.mergeMap(val => 
    fetch('/'+ val + '_state.json', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(res.statusText);
        }
             return res.json();
    })
);
```